Not working middleware tests (maybe my middleware were bad)
It my first middleware to verify tokens. It looks like this:
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using baio_api.Infrastructure.Services.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace baio_api.Common.Middlewares
{
    public class TokenValidationMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
        private readonly ILogger<TokenValidationMiddleware> _logger;

        public TokenValidationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, ILogger<TokenValidationMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _next = next;
            _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("TokenValidationMiddleware invoked.");

            if (!context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Authorization header is missing.");
                await _next(context);
                return;
            }

            var token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Split(" ").Last();
            _logger.LogInformation($"Extracted token: {token}");

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            if (!handler.CanReadToken(token))
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Cannot read token.");
                await _next(context);
                return;
            }

            using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var authService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAuthService>();
                _logger.LogInformation("Checking if token is invalidated.");

                var isInvalidated = await authService.IsTokenInvalidatedAsync(token);

                if (isInvalidated)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("Token is invalidated.");
                    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Token has been invalidated.");
                    return;
                }
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("Token is valid.");
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}

And there is tests:
using System.Net;
using baio_api.Common.Middlewares;
using baio_api.Infrastructure.Services.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Moq;

namespace baio_api.tests.Unit.Common.Middlewares
{
    public class TokenValidationMiddlewareTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task InvokeAsync_TokenIsInvalidated_ReturnsUnauthorized()
        {
            // Arrange
            var authServiceMock = new Mock<IAuthService>();
            authServiceMock.Setup(s => s.IsTokenInvalidatedAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(true);

            var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddLogging(logging =>
                    {
                        logging.AddConsole();
                        logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
                    });
                    services.AddSingleton(authServiceMock.Object);
                    services.AddScoped<TokenValidationMiddleware>();
                })
                .Configure(app =>
                {
                    app.UseMiddleware<TokenValidationMiddleware>();
                    app.Run(async context =>
                    {
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Request passed through middleware.");
                    });
                });

            var server = new TestServer(builder);
            var client = server.CreateClient();

            // Act
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer fake-token");
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, response.StatusCode);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Assert.Equal("Token has been invalidated.", content);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task InvokeAsync_TokenIsValid_ContinuesToNextMiddleware()
        {
            // Arrange
            var authServiceMock = new Mock<IAuthService>();
            authServiceMock.Setup(s => s.IsTokenInvalidatedAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(false);

            var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddLogging(logging =>
                    {
                        logging.AddConsole();
                        logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
                    });
                    services.AddSingleton(authServiceMock.Object);
                    services.AddScoped<TokenValidationMiddleware>();
                })
                .Configure(app =>
                {
                    app.UseMiddleware<TokenValidationMiddleware>();
                    app.Run(async context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Request passed through middleware.");
                    });
                });

            var server = new TestServer(builder);
            var client = server.CreateClient();

            // Act
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer fake-token");
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Assert.Equal("Request passed through middleware.", content);
        }
    }
}

And always I got error in tests:
Failed baio_api.tests.Unit.Common.Middlewares.TokenValidationMiddlewareTests.InvokeAsync_TokenIsInvalidated_ReturnsUnauthorized [30 ms]
Error Message:
Assert.Equal() Failure: Values differ
Expected: Unauthorized
Actual:   OK
Stack Trace:
at baio_api.tests.Unit.Common.Middlewares.TokenValidationMiddlewareTests.InvokeAsync_TokenIsInvalidated_ReturnsUnauthorized() in /Users/oliwierbaran/Projects/baio/baio-api.tests/src/Unit/Common/Middlewares/TokenValidationMiddlewareTests.cs:line 53
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
I tried many times, but I didn't get any logs in terminal or debug console.
There is probability my middleware is just written incorrectly.
This is injected in my app in this file like this:
using baio_api.Common.Middlewares;

public static class MiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static void UseCustomMiddlewares(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<TokenValidationMiddleware>();
    }
}

And program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.ConfigureAuthentication(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.ConfigureSwagger();
builder.Services.ConfigureDbContext(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.ConfigureCors();
builder.Services.ConfigureEmailSettings(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.ConfigureCustomServices();
builder.Services.ConfigureMapper();
builder.Services.ConfigureMediatR();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    });
}

app.UseCors("DevCorsPolicy");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCustomMiddlewares();

app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

Somebody can help me fix my test and tell me about my middleware are correct or not?
Thanks from advice.

Your middleware invokes the next middleware even in the unauthorized-case (which probably leads to the false success-result).
What you wanna do instead is to short-circuit the request pipeline and return immediately.
    // ...
    if (!context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("Authorization header is missing.");
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized; // <- you can add this
        // await _next(context); <- remove this
        return;
    }

    var token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Split(" ").Last();
    _logger.LogInformation($"Extracted token: {token}");

    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    if (!handler.CanReadToken(token))
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("Cannot read token.");
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized; // <- you can add this
        // await _next(context); <- remove this
        return;
    }
    // ...

